# Что не так с JQ кодом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.articles--buttonsFilter-left').on(click, function(){

        $(this).addClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');
$('.articles--buttonsFilter-right').removeClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');

    });

    $('.articles--buttonsFilter-right').on(click, function(){

        $(this).addClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');
$('.articles--buttonsFilter-left').removeClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');

    });
});
```

Захватываю левую кнопку, присваиваю ей класс chosen, одновременно убирая его в правой кнопке. Захватываю правую кнопку, присваиваю тот же класс, параллельно убирая его с левой кнопки. Это я таким образом оставляю кнопку нажатой и сбрасываю это состояние, когда нажимаю другую.
Почему-то не срабатывает.
Ну т.е. левой кнопке класс присваивается и на этом всё заканчивается.

Comment: Что значит захватываете? Capture the flag? Вы обычные клики делаете по кнопкам.

Comment: ... и в результате этих обычных кликов происходит то, что нужно (присвоение класса), но не до конца.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяй в обработчиках событий click на 'click'. Первый параметр в функции 'on' должен быть типа `String`([Doc](http://%20jquery-docs.ru/on)), а ты в данном случае просто как будто передаешь туда переменную, и скорее всего ее значение равно `undefined`, если ты раньше эту переменную не определил.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.articles--buttonsFilter-left').on('click', function(){

        $(this).addClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');
$('.articles--buttonsFilter-right').removeClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');

    });

    $('.articles--buttonsFilter-right').on('click', function(){

        $(this).addClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');
$('.articles--buttonsFilter-left').removeClass('articles--buttonsFilter-chosen');

    });
});
```

```css
.articles--buttonsFilter-chosen {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='articles--buttonsFilter-left'>Left</button>
<button class='articles--buttonsFilter-right'>Right</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Очень странно. Почему же без кавычек срабатывало на первом клике?